# Unable to import Picasa web album in phoca gallery for joomla 3

Tags: php, image, joomla, gallery, picasa

I want to import all my picasa web album into my joomla phoca gallery component. The joomla version is 3 and using `com_phocagallery_v4.1.2` component. After filling up General Option and Picasa(google +) Setting form and click on Picasa Google+ Import button to add a category
it is showing

```
Error

Save failed with the following error: Picasa Album not found. Check the Album field.


Set Picasa (Google+) User : <My User name without @gmail.com>

Set Picasa (Google+) Album : <My Album Name - a string value>
Authentication Key : <My Authentication Key>
```

But if I fetch the following URL `https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/MyUserID/albumid/MyAlbumId?authkey=MyAuthenticationKey&imgmax=d`
It is generating one xml file and showing proper data. That means no issue in my setting. Then how this phoca gallery is not working in joomla 3 - Could you please check and help me?

Comment: I got the solution. I don't know it is totally correct or not. The same thing when I did in my server, is working. In localhost it was not working.

Comment: It is possible that the server blocks the localhost. This can happen, because a lot of requests go from "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" (made by many different users and applications) and such is then blocked.